# Failed to write document on Dynamic Async Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, iframe, asynchronous

I'm using [Dynamic Async Iframe](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance) to load one of our ads and I got this warning and the ads won't load.

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

This is the code I use to load the ad

```
var adSrc = '<?php echo esc_url( $src ); ?>';
        var escapedAdSrc = adSrc.replace(/\//g,'\\/');
        var adWidth = <?php echo $width; ?>;
        var adHeight = <?php echo $height; ?>;
        var theiFrame = document.createElement('iframe');
        theiFrame.frameBorder = 0;
        var iFrame = jQuery('#<?php echo $id; ?>').append(theiFrame);

        var adDoc = theiFrame.contentWindow.document;
        theiFrame.style.cssText = 'width:' + adWidth + 'px;height:' + adHeight +'px;';

        //adDoc.open().write('<body onload="location.href=\'' + escapedAdSrc + '\'">');
        adDoc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
            'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
            'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
            '=\'' + escapedAdSrc + '\'">');
        adDoc.close();
```

I believe partly because ad script has `document.write` in the script that's why I got this error. But I'm not sure how to solve the problem since I the script is third party script.

Comment: I do believe, at least a while ago, that you cannot use client side to write to a document in a frame. I believe this may be why the error is occurring. Is a security threat.

Comment: And there's way to overcome that?